# Implement curl statement inside of ruby on rails action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, curl

How can be the next curl statement implemented in ruby:

```
curl -u <api_key>:x -H Accept:application/pdf -H Content-Type:application/pdf https://acme.chargify.com/statements/1.pdf > output_file.pdf
```

I need to call to chargify inside of my controller action and return the result to user. Is it possible to do it without gems like curb, only by using Net::HTTP?

Comment: Any reason you're not to use the Chargify gem? https://github.com/chargify/chargify_api_ares

Comment: Already use that gem but I can't get a pdf statement with it.

Comment: Are you sure? According to [the docs](https://docs.chargify.com/api-invoices), "Individual PDF Invoices can be retrieved by using the `Accept/Content-Type` header `application/pdf` or appending `.pdf` as the `<format>` portion of the URL".

Answer (score 1):

```
uri = URI.parse('https://acme.chargify.com/statements/1.pdf')

http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)

request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri)
request.basic_auth(<api_key>, x)
request['Accept'] = 'application/pdf'
request['Content-Type'] = 'application/pdf'

response = http.request(request)

File.open('output_file.pdf', 'w') { |f| f.puts response.body }
```

Answer (score 0):

`Typhoeus` maybe? https://github.com/typhoeus/typhoeus

You can specify your -u flag like this:

```
Typhoeus::Request.get("https://example.com", userpwd: "<api_key>:x")
```